# Vue.js ready() method doesn't get called in vue component

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using Webpack bundler to serve Vue 2.0 based frontend. The problem is that method `ready` in components doesn't get called. Do I need to add some extra watch on component or something like that?

My router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

import Register from './views/auth/register.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueResource);

const routes = [
  { path: '/auth/register', component: Register } 
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for routes: routes
})

export default router;
```

and my sample component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="message">{{ msg }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    data: function () {
        return {
            msg: 'Hello from vue-loader!'
        }
    },

    ready: function() {
        console.log('test');
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's because it's depracated in Vue 2 - use `mounted()` or `created()`

Comment: @BelminBedak That's the answer! Thank you very much. Please add is as an aswer so I can accept it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ready()` lifecycle hook method is depracated in VueJS 2.0.x.Use `mounted()` or `created()` instead.

Comment: but what is alternative?

Comment: @AdrianoResende alternative is to use mounted instead of ready.

Comment: But `mounted() { console.log(document.readyState) }` is `interactive` and not `complete` (after load all image and files)

Comment: @AdrianoResende VueJS lifecycle hooks cares only about Vue instance.

Answer (score 5):

If you need run code after 100% loaded with **image** and **files**, test this in `mounted()`:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    console.log('Page completed with image and files!')
    // fetch
  }
}
```

More info: [MDN Api onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

Comment: sometimes it may be also useful to look for libraries initialization hooks, in my case I am dealing with `fullcalendar` and `eventAfterAllRender` was the answer